Incorrect bounding box with PIL text rendering
I am trying to render a custom font using PIL since tkinter doesn't support custom fonts. My approach is to load in the font, and then draw it on an image, and then size the image to be the same size as the bounding box of the text. This works ok, but it cuts off the last few pixels of letters, and for letters like p and y, it cuts off the bottom tail. Here is my code:
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk


def render_text(text, font_path, font_size):
    custom_font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, font_size)

    temp_img = Image.new("RGBA", (1, 1))  # Dummy size
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(temp_img)

    bbox = draw.textbbox((0, 0), text, font=custom_font)

    text_width = bbox[2] - bbox[0]
    text_height = bbox[3] - bbox[1]

    img = Image.new("RGBA", (text_width, text_height), color="white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    draw.text((0, 0), text, font=custom_font, fill="black")

    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Test')
font_path = 'fonts/coolvetica condensed rg.otf'
custom_font_image = render_text("POLwefwogkpw", font_path, 64)
label = tk.Label(root, image=custom_font_image)
label.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()

I tried increasing the bounding box size, but that seems inconsistent across different pieces of text. I'm not too familiar with the PIL library, so I wasn't really sure what else to try. I can't really make the image a set size for what I need it for as there are multiple background colors that would lead to the GUI looking weird. I'm expecting to just get an image that has the text rendered in the custom font, without too much empty background space around it. Looking at the documentation for textbbox, it says it only supports TrueType files, but I also tried with a different font that was TrueType and it still had the same error where the tails of letters like y and p were cut off. Thanks!

Please think about your question... you have defined a function, which you never call, from an incomplete script with no import statements, that writes some unspecified text in an unspecified font without showing the expected or actual results and you'd like us to tell you what's wrong. If you'd like folks to assist you, consider making it easy for them to do so.
